# How to write async actions in play framework 2.5?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework

I wrote the following code to send an email as non-blocking action.
It's not working for more than 1 request.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
 EmailService.sendVerificationMail(appUser , mailString)).
  thenApply(i -> ok("Got result: " + i));
```

As `play.Promise` is deprecated in play.2.5 (java). My previous code is not supporting. So please give me proper solution to make my action as non-blocking.

Comment: good way to ask question:  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Can u please explain whats wrong in my question. Actually this is my first question on Stack overflow ..

Comment: You may get more attention if you gave more details.think of yourself in other person shoes who is answering

Comment: Ok.I got your point Thanks

Comment: Have you worked on play framework @ TheGameiswar ?

Answer (score 3):

If the function `EmailService.sendVerificationMail` is blocking, `CompletableFuture` only makes it non-blocking on the calling thread. In fact it is still blocking on other thread (probably the common `ForkJoinPool`).

This is not a problem if only several email tasks are running. But if there are too many email tasks (say 100 or more), they will "dominate" the pool. This causes "Convoy effect" and other tasks have to wait much more time to start. This can badly damage the server performance.

If you have a lot of concurrent email tasks, you can create your own pool to handles them, instead of using the common pool. Thread pool is better than fork join pool because it does not allow work-stealing.

Or you can find the asynchronous APIs of `EmailService`, or implement them on your own if possible.

To answer the other question, now Play 2.5 uses `CompletionStage` for the default promise. It should work if you just use `CompletionStage`.

Some example code here. Note the use of `CompletionStage` in the return type.

```
public CompletionStage<Result> testAction() {
    return CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> EmailService.sendVerificationMail(appUser, mailString), EmailService.getExecutor())
            .thenApply(i -> ok("Got result: " + i));
}
```

For more details, you may check the [Java Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaMigration25#Replaced-F.Promise-with-Java-8s-CompletionStage) on Play's site.

Comment: Thanks  @HKTonyLee. I will try to implement ur code. Can u plz tell me few async email api's.?

Comment: Hii @HKTonuLee , above code is also blocking the function.When I tried with below code its became non-blocking but sometimes its not working.

Comment: Hii @HKTonuLee , above code is also blocking the function.When I tried with below code its became non-blocking but sometimes its not working.   public Result sendEmail() {                    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> EmailService.sendVerificationMail(appUser , "Email verification for your Account")).thenApply(i -> ok("Got r esult: " + i));                                          return ok();  }  This method is working fine I cant understand what is difference between two of above Please help me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public static CompletableFuture<Result> asynchronousProcessTask() {
        final CompletableFuture<Boolean> promise = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> Locate365Util.doTask());
        return promise.thenApplyAsync(
                (final Boolean i) -> ok("The Result of promise" + promise));
    }

** doTask() method must return boolean value
```